# Should I rename internal references to a feature name if it's name in the UI has changed?

Tags: refactoring, rename, naming-conventions, naming

During development, an internal name is given to a particular feature. That name is then used in function and variable names. Later, when the UI and Documentation are finalized, a different public-facing name is assigned to that feature. Should variable names be renamed too to correspond to the new public name?

On one side, the public-facing name may change frequently and so it is unpractical to rename internal references all the time. On the other hand, it can create confusion in meetings and among new team members if a single feature has different names (should there be a spreadsheet that maps the public and private names?).

Is there an industry standard for this?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more concrete. What names are we talking about?

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom any variable/function name. For example, a React component is called "MappingView", which renders a "Mapping View" UI component. Later, the marketing team decided to call this part of the UI a "Map Editor". Should I rename React component and other occurrences to "MapEditor" or is it okay for React component name to differ from the name used in the documentation? This doesn't just apply to react components. For example, picklist/combo box/drop-down list/select element - internal and external names for these may also differ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of an "ubiquitous language" discusses how external and internal names should be consistent.

To quote [this](https://thedomaindrivendesign.io/developing-the-ubiquitous-language/) great article:

> Ubiquitous Language is the term that Eric Evans uses in “Domain-Driven
> Design – Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software” in order to
> build a language shared by the team, developers, domain experts, and
> other participants.

Using consistent names makes it easier for all parties to understand concepts in the product and code.